# SetServiceStatus succeeds but appears to have no effect

Tags: c#, service

I followed this [MSDN walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for writing a service by deriving from ServiceBase. It suggests a way to call SetServiceStatus to indicate SERVICE_STOP_PENDING. I gather this means that your process won't be terminated until you call it with SERVICE_STOPPED. I overrode OnStop and added this code:

```
                checkpoint = 1;
                // Update the service state to Stop Pending.
                ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus();

                serviceStatus.dwServiceType = ServiceType.SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
                serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
                serviceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 1;
                serviceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
                serviceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
                serviceStatus.dwCheckPoint = checkpoint++;
                serviceStatus.dwWaitHint = 10000;

                SetLastError(0);
                if (!SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus))
                    TextOut("OnStop SetServiceStatus failed: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                timer.Interval = 50;
                timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
                timer.Start();
```

However timer_Elapsed doesn't get called and my process is abruptly terminated. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It already has that status value while your OnStop() method runs.  Provided by ServiceBase.  So no obvious reason to help.

Comment: Right. I was looking for a way remain in the stopping state after I returned from OnStop.  The walk-through I referenced has you set status to START_PENDING in the OnStart method; from your comment I'd guess that's unnecessary too; and they set the status to RUNNING at the end of the method; also unnecessary I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question. I decided to use a simple sleep() in a loop while waiting for the process to finish cleaning up, so I won't be using ServiceStatus.

It appeared that once you return from OnStop() you're unconditionally terminated but that's just a guess.

Comment: It does, obviously. why would service doesn't terminate after you exit from OnStop. SetServiceStatus is for the times that your service have massive cleanup to do before stopping (or starting) and It takes longer than default timeout to stop/start service. in these situations you call SetServiceStatus to let SCM know that you are still busy cleaning/setting up, while you are running your OnStop, OnStart Code.